# Read 120(total 10gb) csv-files into a DataFrame in R adding a column with filename

Tags: r

I have 120 csv-files with total size of 10gb.
I want to import these files in R to a dataFrame.
The ColumnNames don't match exactly so I need a function that Union all my tables from the folder.
I would also like to add the filename in a column.

Iv'e managed to create a dataframe but without the extra filename-column in the code below.

```
csvFiles <- list.files(pattern ="*csv")

df = do.call(rbind.fill , lapply (csvFiles, read.csv, sep";"))
```

Is there a simple way to just add the extra filename column?

Comment: Do you want to create a column with the file names inside each file or in one file all the different file names? Are you planning to join these data frames after fixing the column names?

Comment: See here for an example: https://www.gerkelab.com/blog/2018/09/import-directory-csv-purrr-readr/

Comment: I want one file with an extra column that tells each elements source.

Answer (score 1):

This `tidyverse`-solution should work, allthough it might be kind of slow:

```r
library(tidyverse)
csvFiles <- list.files(pattern ="*csv")
df <- csvFiles %>%
  map_dfr(~read_delim(.,delim = ';'),.id = 'source')
```

If you want to keep your filenames, you just have to recode them since the 'source'-column will just be a numeric index. One way to do that would be to just add

```
  mutate(source = csvFiles[as.numeric(source)])
```

to the pipeline.

Comment: I get the error "cannot allocate vector of size xx"
But it worked fine on 30-40 files

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to load A LOT of stuff into your working memory. You might want to split your files into chunks and work with the relevant one.

Comment: Yes I will look into that.
Thanks Btw!